# Replace text using regex function in RStudio

Tags: regex, rstudio

I'm trying to use the regex function in RStudio search box (you can tick a box to match regex content). Below is the content I have *in an R script* (it's actually an R Markdown).

```
---
## Prerequisites

[more text]
```

I want to match

```
---
##
```

And replace it by

```
---
#
```

I've used this command

```
/(^---\n## )/gm
```

but it doesn't work. It worked with the online regex solver https://regex101.com.

1. So how to have a regex that can perform that
2. More generally, what syntax is assumed in the search box in RStudio
3. does the replace option has to be in regex as well?

Comment: With a little experimentation, it looks like the built-in RStudio regex find/replace doesn't work with multiline patterns. In a simple case of `a` one line and `b` on the next line, I can't seem to get it to match the two-line pattern.

Comment: Well, that's good to know!